# How to use react js computed property to access a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I made a fading text component, it's just a header with transition opacity css and a visibility state so I can make the text fade in and out. I have a lot of these fading text objects so I'm simplifying things making a fading text group component. I want the group to be created using a string array passed in the props, for this I need to use the map function to create a bunch of these fading texts, but I can't access the created state using computed property.

```
this.setState({
        fadeTexts: this.props.values.map((buttonText, index) => {
            this.setState({ ["fade" + index]: false });
            <FadeInText value={buttonText} visible={this.state.["fade" + index]} />
        }).bind(this)
    });
```

How can I both set and access a state using computed property?

Comment: This is unrelated but `this.state.["fade" + index]` is invalid syntax, you have an extra `.` character in there before the `[`.

Comment: You can't set state inside a setState call. You also shouldn't be storing groups of HTML components in state. Create a new component for that. State is more for storing transitory data that shows your app's configuration at a given point in time.  That aside, is it possible to rephrase what you are trying to, what is the end result you are aiming for, it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're probably better of just having a single boolean value inside state that controls the visibility of all of the buttons:

```
render() {
  return this.props.values.map(buttonText => 
    <FadeInText key={buttonText} value={buttonText} visible={this.state.fadeTextVisible} />
  );
}
```

Then toggle `state.fadeTextVisible` in your button click handler:

```
handleButtonClick() {
  this.setState({ fadeTextVisible: !this.state.fadeTextVisible });
}
```

If you need to control the visibility of each piece of text individually, use an array inside state.